# Using ngx-markdown giving static injector error

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Using ng-markdown in one project and then building that as a library and then using it in another project gives below error with ng build --prod, it works fine without --prod build

NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MarkdownComponent -> MarkdownService]: ...

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, it's related to ngx-bootstrap. You mentioned ng-markdown here